# Values not returned correctly

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

this is my scenario. I want to read values from data in a Excel worksheet "Sheet2". How can I read the values of specific cells into variables that I can use to do computations and so on? This is what I have but I'm not getting it to work. Am I missing something?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select

Dim i, iHdr, iLine, sOutStr
Dim sDatum, sVerskaf As String
Dim sNr, sBoL, sPOOrder, sStockCode, sOrder, sVragbief, sNommer, sBondel, sLotNum,    sKaartjie, sKode, sM3Hash, sStukke, sLengte, sBreedte, sDikte, sM3At, sM3, sEen
Dim sXML

i = 3

For Each sCellA In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i & ":B10")
    i = i + 1
    sDatum = Cells(i, 1).Value
    sVerskaf = Cells(i, 2).Value
    sNr = Cells(i, 3).Value
    sBoL = Cells(i, 4).Value
    sPOOrder = Cells(i, 5).Value
    sStockCode = Cells(i, 6).Value
    sXML = "<Info><Date>" & sDatum & "</Date>"
    sXML = sXML & "<Supplier>" & sVerskaf & "</Supplier>"
    sXML = sXML & "<Number>" & sNr & "</Number>"
    sXML = sXML & "<BoL>" & sBoL & "</BoL>"
    sXML = sXML & "<PurchaseOrder>" & sPOOrder & "</PurchaseOrder>"
    sXML = sXML & "<StockCode>" & sStockCode & "</StockCode></Info>"
Next
'MsgBox sXML, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. You cannot use a `For Each` like that.  `For Each` iterates through a range of objects without the need for an indexing value ( like `i`), a regular For loop is used for iterating through cells using the `Sheet.Cells(i,j)` option
2. And since you are referencing a single column of values you don't even need a for loop at all, just access the cells directly `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3,1)` or `ActiveSheet.Cells(3,2)` etc.
3. And lastly you need not assign those values to variables, you can simple use the cell values directly in the xml formation: `sXML = "<Info><Date>" & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3,1).Value & "</Date>"`

Comment: Another stupid question: Do I need to declare the variables as String or will a dim variable be fine to store any value?

Comment: Assuming you're using a newer version vba, say from Excel 2007+, you can declare the variables to be whatever type they need to be.  VBA is pretty forgiving with implicit conversion from a Range Value to Variable

Comment: @user3180965 Either, you can declare it as string or variant but VBA programmers suggest not to always resort to variant data type to capture unexpected programming errors.

Comment: Very true.  Type Checking is a wonderful thing.  Be sure to set `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict On` at the top of your code

Comment: How do I get the last row with data

Comment: not sure what you mean, can you edit your post with your latest code?